# Integral of function with any test function along curve vanishes. Does that imply that the function must vanish?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, distribution-theory

**Situation**: I have a smooth curve $\gamma:(a,b)\to\mathbb R^n$ and a locally integrable function $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb R$ for which I know that $\int_a^b f(t)\phi(\gamma(t))\text{d}t = 0$ for any smooth, compactly supported $\phi:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$.

**I'm trying to figure out**: *Does this imply that $f = 0$ almost everywhere?*

**Some ideas...:**
The situation is very similar to the statement that if $\int_a^b f(t)\tilde \phi(t)\text{d}t = 0$ for any smooth, compactly supported $\tilde\phi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ then this does indeed imply that $f = 0$ almost everywhere. If $\gamma$ were injective, I believe we could reduce our case to this simpler case, because given any $\tilde \phi$ we could choose $\phi$ such that $\phi\circ\gamma = \tilde\phi$. However, in when $\gamma$ is not injective, I have no idea how to prove the statement or even if it holds at all.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Let $\gamma (t) = \sin t$ for $0 \leq t \leq \pi$ and $f(t) = \cos t$. Then for any smooth $\phi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and with an antiderivative $\Phi$ of $\phi$, we have $$\int_{0}^{\pi}f(t)\phi(\gamma(t))\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_{0}^{\pi}\phi(\sin t)\cos t\,\mathrm{d}t=[\Phi(\sin t)]_{0}^{\pi}=0.$$

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks for the counterexample! Interesting...  so it seems that the statement is not generally true when $\gamma$ is not injective